# Is it a security risk to include public key in a composer package?

Tags: composer-php, public-key

I am making a composer library which requires a public key to verify some data, send from a server.

I have generated the key pair, and the private key is of course kept safe on the server, encrypting the data, but I am looking for the best way of distributing the public key and (for me at least), it makes sense to include it in the composer package, to make it user friendly, and a lot more transparent.

BUT is there any security considerations with this approach, or anything else you can think of?
Would you distribute the public key in the package, together with the code consuming the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public keys are meant to be shared, so is ok to include it. For example https websites give you their public key. On the other hand, a private key should be secret and accessible only to the owner.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's a **public** key. You can share it everywhere.